# How to pass BuildConfig to workbench rest api

Tags: rest, maven, drools, workbench

Following workbench rest api documentation says we can pass BundleConfig to maven/compile post call but I couldn't find an example of BundleConfig json. I want to bump up the version number of my project when i issue maven compile.

[POST] /repositories/{repositoryName}/projects/{projectName}/maven/compile
Compiles the project (equivalent to mvn compile)

Consumes a BuildConfig instance. While this must be supplied, it's not needed for the operation and may be left blank.

Returns a CompileProjectRequest instance

Comment: I'm also struggling to find how to use a BuildConfig with maven requests [link](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#d0e18666). I think the documentation is poor/out-of-date. For 6.2.0.Final there is no kie-wb-common-services project in mvn repo, which suggests a change in usage...

Answer (score 0):

I've found this works:

```
BuildConfig buildConfig = new BuildConfig();

InstallProjectRequest response = restTemplate.postForObject(
URL_MVN_INSTALL, new HttpEntity<>(buildConfig, createHeaders()), InstallProjectRequest.class);
```

However, I don't think its possible to use buildConfig to update the version number (not yet anyway).

But you can achieve the same result by embedding the application in an iframe and using some javascript/jquery magic.